# Leer datos en modo remoto mediante Curl

Tags: php, curl

No he trabajado nunca con Curl, y de ahí mi pregunta.
Estoy tratando de leer un archivo (dato.php) en modo remoto mediante Curl.
Les dejo el contenido del archivo el cual contiene un array (Ej: https://miweb.com/dato.php)

```
$data = array(
'code'  => 'mi_codigo',
'email'  => 'email@hotmail.com',
'item' => '32010502');
```

Y ahora la llamada de Curl que realizo en una parte de mi codigo.

```
        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://miweb.com/dato.php';
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'code' => $CODE,
        'email' => $EMAIL,
        'item' => $ITEM));
        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        $object = json_decode($buffer);
```

La pregunta es como leo los parametros de mi archivo datos.php??
He intentado con echo $object->code;
Pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener el código php contenido en el archivo dato.php? o ¿Quieres obtener el resultado de la ejecución del script dato.php? Si en dato.php asignas valores para `code`, `email` y `item` ¿Por qué mandas en `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` a dato.php `$CODE`, `$EMAIL` y `$ITEM`?. Parece que quieres de regreso lo mismo que envías.

Comment: Si, es verdad lo hice rápido y añadi variables... quiero obtener el valor de 'code' 'email' 'id' .  O sea 'mi_codigo' ...Gracias

Comment: Intentaste con.un `echo $buffer` para ver que datos te devuelve?si es un json? podrias mostrar el json

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Depura tu respuesta de cURL con un `var_dump($buffer);` revisa lo que aparece en pantalla, y si a partir de ahí no sabes qué hacer edita la pregunta poniendo lo que sale por pantalla desde el `var_dump`.

Comment: //edito el curl
                        $curl_handle = curl_init();
   $url = 'https://miweb.com/dato.php';
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
   curl_close($curl_handle);
      
   var_dump($buffer);

Comment: //salida var_dump:  string(0) ""

Comment: Recibis un Json con datos?

Comment: No, era otro archivo. Lo quiero hacer de un modo mas sencillo, un simple array

Comment: Se trata de leer un array de un archivo PHP, como puede ser https://miweb.com/dato.php. Y desde otro sitio web leer la informacion de dicho array mediante Curl. He puesto el codigo pero no logro leerlo. Alguna sugerencia ?